# Synchronise PHP server and android countdown timers

Tags: javascript, php, android

I'm creating an android game timer. The countdown timer in PHP server should be equal to the timer in android app. Timer should always run. If the game finished, It should create a new timer for the next game. Should I use Server time or I have to set fixed time for game?

Comment: If you use a fix time then you don't have to worry about synchronizing between each device. Each device would just count down to that time. Does every user have a timer or is everyone has the same?

Comment: Everyone has the same time. They will get the time PHP server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a database to store the time the game started, then you can call up the current time from the server/database as well as the start time of the game and use a function in your android app to countdown/calculate the difference.

More detail might be key for better answers.

Cheers!

Comment: Hi @Luke,  What do you think I can do to make sure that every android user has the same timer.